# Web Scraping while meeting a condition

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, tags

I am scraping some data from this site: https://masteroverwatch.com/profile/pc/us/calvin-1337, specifically `span.summary-hero-name`. This is my code to do so:

```
scrapeIt("https://masteroverwatch.com/profile/pc/us/calvin-1337",  {
  title: "span.summary-hero-name"
}).then(page => {
  console.log(page.title)
});
```

This returns `McreeWidowmakerBastion` which it should do, as there are 3 heros with the class `summary-hero-name`, but I only want the first one in the source code (which is the most used). If that is not possible then I would want to meet the condition where `href` is `/profile/pc/us/Calvin-1337/heroes/6` (which IS the top one).

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? I would be curious to see if you can replace title: with span.summary-hero-name:first to grab the first hero only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need advanced CSS selectors!

One may think about `:first-child` or `:first-of-type`, but it does not work as we could expect... I have analyzed the page you shared and I think you want the following selector:

`a[href$="/heroes/6"] + .row`

I have reproduced the use case with the interesting part of the HTML code. The red `div` is the one you are trying to select. It contains all the information you need.

```css
.row {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

a[href$="/heroes/6"] + .row {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-heroes-summary widget">
  <div class="widget-title">Favorite Hero Performance</div>
    <div class="summary-list">
      <div class="summary-row-container">
        <a class="summary-row-link" href="/profile/pc/us/Calvin-1337/heroes/6"></a>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="summary-icon col-xs-5">
            <span class="summary-icon-unit" style="background-image:url('https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/hero/mccree/hero-select-portrait.png');"></span>
            <strong>
              <span class="summary-hero-name">McCree</span>
              <div class="summary-hero-role">Offense</div>
            </strong>
           </div>
           <div class="summary-stats col-xs-4">
            <div class="summary-stats-kda stats-assists">
              <strong>3.44</strong>:1 K/D
            </div>
            <div class="summary-stats-kills">
              <span>7,443 / 2,166</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="summary-winrate col-xs-3">
            <strong class="stats-kills">58.5%</strong>
            <span>340 Games</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="summary-row-container">
        <a class="summary-row-link" href="/profile/pc/us/Calvin-1337/heroes/9"></a>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="summary-icon col-xs-5">
             <span class="summary-icon-unit" style="background-image:url('https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/hero/widowmaker/hero-select-portrait.png');"></span>
             <strong>
               <span class="summary-hero-name">Widowmaker</span>
               <div class="summary-hero-role">Defense</div>
             </strong>
           </div>
           <div class="summary-stats col-xs-4">
            <div class="summary-stats-kda stats-assists">
              <strong>4.29</strong>:1 K/D
            </div>
            <div class="summary-stats-kills">
              <span>6,827 / 1,590</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="summary-winrate col-xs-3">
            <strong class="stats-kills">64.6%</strong>
            <span>339 Games</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="summary-row-container">
        <a class="summary-row-link" href="/profile/pc/us/Calvin-1337/heroes/15"></a>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="summary-icon col-xs-5">
            <span class="summary-icon-unit" style="background-image:url('https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/hero/bastion/hero-select-portrait.png');"></span>
            <strong>
              <span class="summary-hero-name">Bastion</span>
              <div class="summary-hero-role">Defense</div>
            </strong>
          </div>
        <div class="summary-stats col-xs-4">
          <div class="summary-stats-kda stats-assists">
            <strong>3.01</strong>:1 K/D
          </div>
          <div class="summary-stats-kills">
            <span>810 / 269</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="summary-winrate col-xs-3">
          <strong class="stats-kills">61.4%</strong>
          <span>44 Games</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="/profile/pc/us/Calvin-1337/heroes" class="summary-more-link">View More</a>
</div>
```